# cakephp plugin routes works in Apache but fails in Nginx

Tags: cakephp, nginx

Have baked plugin Admin. Devel server runs Apache , all the plugins files are loaded. Production server runs Nginx , set virtual server as described in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#nginx
All is well except media and script files in the plugin - all these files are not found (404 Not Found). Those files are loaded well in the Apache version.Can someone suggest a correct Nginx settings ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry , my error. Files' access was wrong